# How to create an independant page in Doxygen that is not in the menu

Tags: doxygen

I have a library for which I am generating doxygen documentation. 
There is a module (module_A) in that library which contains a description of various details in relation to this module (on generated page group_moduleA.html). 
I want to add several pages to give additional details about that module, which I will then link to from the module page. However, I do not want those pages to be visible in any of the left hand menu. I only want them to be linked to from the group_moduleA.html page and nowhere else. 
Is there any way to do that?

I cannot use \page, as a page will be added in the left hand menu if I do that.